# angularjs ui-router parent state with parameter loads after child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a parent and a child state.
The parent state is used to View/Edit customers, the child state is to create.
Without a parameter on the parent state, they both load fine:

```
.state('crm.customer', {
    url: 'crm/customers/',
    templateUrl: 'src/modules/crm/views/customer.html',
    controller: 'customersController'
})
.state('crm.customer.create', {
    url: 'crm/customers/create',
    templateUrl: 'src/modules/crm/views/customer.html',
    controller: 'customersController'
})
```

When I add the `customerId` parameter to the parent state, and I load the child state, first the child state loads, and then immediately it switches to the parent state:

```
.state('crm.customer', {
    url: 'crm/customers/:customerId',
    templateUrl: 'src/modules/crm/views/customer.html',
    controller: 'customersController'
})
.state('crm.customer.create', {
    url: 'crm/customers/create',
    templateUrl: 'src/modules/crm/views/customer.html',
    controller: 'customersController'
})
```

How can I prevent the parent state from loading after the child state loads?

Comment: This happens because both your paths match when you access the `/crm/customers/create` path. In this case, the `:customerId` takes the value of `create`. try `url: 'crm/customers/{customerId:int}'` instead of `url: 'crm/customers/:customerId'`

Comment: @iulian Nice, thanks! :D Add this as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you access `/crm/customers/create`, both state urls matches. In order to solve this problem, define the type of the param. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#basic-parameters), there are several ways to define the params within a url, one of which is using curly braces: `'/user/{id:int}'`.

In your case, use

```
.state('crm.customer', {
  url: 'crm/customers/{customerId:int}',
  templateUrl: 'src/modules/crm/views/customer.html',
  controller: 'customersController'
})
```

so that `/crm/customers/create` will match only the child's state.